# Access a Java object's variables from an object which is itself a variable of the target object?

Tags: java, class, object, oop

I have written three Java classes:

- `Company`
- `Department`
- `Employee`

Each `Company` object contains an array of `Department` objects, which in turn contain arrays of `Employee` objects.

I want to write a method in the `Employee` class `setQid()` which will set a unique ID for that employee in the following format:

- compName_deptName_deptNumber_empFirstName_empSurname

Example:

- "Microsoft_Accounting_3_John_Smith"

My question is: how can I access the following variables from the context of my `Employee` class?

- `String name` in `Company`
- `String name` in `Department`
- `int number` in `Department`

Please see my code below:

```
public class Company {

    private String name;
    private Department[] departments;

    public Company(String name, Department[] departments) {

        this.name = name;
        this.departments = departments;
    }
}


public class Department {

    private String name;
    private int number;
    private Employee[] members;

    public Department(String name, int number, Employee[] members) {

        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.members = members;
    }
}


public class Employee {

    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    private String qid; //A unique employee ID

    public Employee(String firstname, String surname) {

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.surname = surname;
        setQid();
    }

    public void setQid() {

        // How can I access the Company name, Department name, and Department number from here?
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. In your current setup an `Employee` does not have a `Company`, you can create a new `Employee` from thin air without any `Company` defined anywhere.

Comment: @luk2302 But the ```Company``` has a ```Department``` which has an ```Employee``` right? There's no way to access data in this direction?

Comment: Not if you just have reference to the `Employee`, no.

Comment: Guess I will have to rethink my class structure then. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a reference for the Department in your Employee class and a reference for the Company in your Department, only then will your relationships amongst your entities will be complete.

```
public class Company {

    private String name;
    private Department[] departments;

    public Company(String name, Department[] departments) {

        this.name = name;
        this.departments = departments;
    }
    //add getters and setters
}

public class Department {

    private String name;
    private int number;
    private Employee[] members;
    private Company company;

    public Department(String name, int number, Employee[] members) {

        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.members = members;
    }


    //add getters and setters
}

public class Employee {

    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    private String qid; //A unique employee ID
    private Department department;

    public Employee(String firstname, String surname) {

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.surname = surname;
        setQid();
    }

    public void setQid() {
     
      qid = department.getCompany().getName + "_" + department.getName() ....

    }

    //add getters and setters
}
```